# Overriding AuthorizeCore from AuthorizeAttribute is not being invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

For some reason, only the method `OnAuthorization` is being invoked, but `AuthorizeCore` not.
this is how I call it:

```
[AuthorizeWithRoles(Roles = "Affiliate")]
public string TestOnlyAffiliate()
{
     return "ok";
}
```

this is the actual attribute.

```
public class AuthorizeWithRolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public string Roles { get; set; }

    //
    //AuthorizeCore - NOT INVOKING!
    //
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public  void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You're not supposed to override `OnAuthorization`. It deals with potential caching issues and calls `AuthorizeCore`.

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1acb241299a8#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs

```
// In the worst case this could allow an authorized user
// to cause the page to be cached, then an unauthorized user would later be served the
// cached page.
```

Put your custom logic in `AuthorizationCore`.

Comment: The problem with going to `AuthorizeCore` is that you lose `filterContext`, couldn't you just call `base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);` at the beginning of your overridden `OnAuthrization` to make sure that this cache thing is a non-issue?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this helps you at all, but I ran into this same thing and determined that, at least for my purposes, I didn't need to override AuthorizeCore at all. I'm not sure why it's there, to be honest. As MSDN says, OnAuthorization is invoked "when a process requests authorization." This means that it will be invoked for any method that has your AuthorizeWithRoles attribute. You can put your custom code within OnAuthorization to check whether or not the user has permission, and since you can get the httpContext from filterContext, there's really no need for AuthorizeCore. Here's a simple example that works for me:

```
public class LoginRequired : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Common.ValidateCurrentSession(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
            //this is valid; keep going
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //this is not valid; redirect
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/login");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps. Besides that, obviously you'll need to declare that OnAuthorization is an override.

EDIT: I believe the base OnAuthorization method is what calls into AuthorizeCore. Since you're overriding OnAuthorization, obviously that call is lost. I believe overriding AuthorizeCore would only be relevant if you left OnAuthorization alone or if you called base.OnAuthorization(filterContext) within the overridden method.

Comment: -1 You're not supposed to override `OnAuthorization`, you're introducing a security issue. See my answer.